Interpreting roots of multiplicity greater than 1 in characteristic polynomial in generating functions
This might be a stupid problem...
In Wilf's Generatingfunctionology he proposed a method to solve the following "initial value problem" $$ (a+bx+cx^2)U(x) = x(D(x)+au_1+cu_{N-1}x^N) $$
$a, b, c, D(x)$ are known and we want to solve for $u_1, u_{N-1}$. If the roots to the quadratic on LHS are real and different then we get 2 equations and we can solve for those. But if we get a root of multiplicity 2, where does the other extra relation come from?
I mean in ODE if we get a root of multiplicity k, the solutions becomes $e^{rx},xe^{rx}, ..., x^{k-1}e^{rx}$ respectively. How do I multiply the "x" in this sense?
